# Why requestLocationUpdates fire immediatly onReceive?

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

When i execute requestLocationUpdates like this :

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);    

LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(150000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(900000);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);

fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, getPendingIntent(context));
```

then the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` is immediatly fired without taking care of the `setMaxWaitTime(900000)`. Is it a normal/documented behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

In [LocationUpdatesPendingIntent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatespendingintent/MainActivity.java) there is a small disclaimer:

```
    // Sets the maximum time when batched location updates are delivered. Updates may be
    // delivered sooner than this interval.
    mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME);
```

Comment: thanks Melix, however what mean sooner ? immediatly (like I notice), 1 min? 10 min? In fact what i would like to know it's what they mean by "sooner", for the very first call to requestLocationUpdates